# c# accessing variables defined in different .cs files

Tags: c#

It may be the basic of c#.But, I can't find out a solution..

I have 3 classes (let it be 1.cs,2.cs,3.cs) in my application. I want to use in 3.cs class, a variable or string  that is defined in 2.cs. How can it be done?

Comment: You're right, it is basic. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288463(v=vs.71).aspx - This was found via a google of "C# tutorial". First example.

Comment: I think you should learn C# before posting here.

Comment: http://www.csharp-station.com/tutorial.aspx

Comment: When you create different classes with Visual Studio in the same project, it normally puts all of those classes in the same `namespace`.  Have you tried just using the variable as though they're in the same file?  If that doesn't compile, than post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) so we can see where you went wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Declare the string or variable you want to access as `PUBLIC` in 2.cs
2) Create an object of class 2.cs in 3.cs
3) Access the variable using this object.

Comment: I think that this solution won't work :P second point should be "Create an object of class 2 in class 3" am I right? :)

Comment: A class cannot start with a number. :P

Comment: I think it's just for an example :)

Answer (score 2):

if is is an not static class then u can use it like that

```
 2 csFileNo2=new 2();

 csFileNo2.YourStringVar;
```

or if this is an static class like

```
class static 2
{
  public static csFileNo2="Your string";
}
```

then use it like that

```
 2.csFileNo2;
```

remember that its just an example . numbers are not allow as first char of class or function name .

best of luck

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways to access variables in other classes, the easiest way to this is by using Inheritance, for instance:

```
public class C1 {
   public static int x;
}    

public class C2 : C1 {
   //Now this class can access the x value from the C1 class
}
```

another way to do this without inheritence would be to access the variable this way  :

```
C1.x
```

You can read about inheritance in [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @nyarlathotep: you are right, I'll edit my answer.