# using variables from another file .cs

Tags: c#

I have a project in c# winforms, with a file called: `PublicSettings.cs` (this file is within a folder called: Class) where I have a variable.

Now, I want to use that variable from another file within the same project.

**PublicSettings.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace LVSetup.Class
{
    class PublicSettings
    {        
        private string _ConnStr = "Connection";

        public string ConnStr
        {
            get
            {
                return this._ConnStr;
            }
            set
            {
                this._ConnStr = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use the variable `ConnStr` in the file: `frmLogin.cs`

**frmLogin.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using LVSetup.Class;

namespace LVSetup
{
    public partial class frmLogin : Form
    {
        public frmLogin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            string a = PublicSettings.ConnStr;
        }
    }
}
```

But there is no `ConnStr` within `PublicSettings`, just (Equals and ReferenceEquals)

What could be wrong here?

Comment: The problem is you are trying to access a non-static variable from a static context

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about core c# syntax and can be easily resolved by reading carefully through the documentation and tutorials.

Comment: @walther, thats a great downvote reason.. not a great close reason.

Comment: @paqogomez, SO is plagued by questions like this and I'm sure someone would easily find numerous duplicates on the very same topic. There are more reasons to close this one... Questions like this are only good for rep hunters who want easy points...

Comment: @paqogomez The class doesn't need to be public - it is internal by default, and the calling class s in the same project.

Comment: Why do people get so mad about rep hunting? We should be inclusive of people who are trying to understand programming better, not using them as a battleground over rep wars.

Comment: @walther, then find a dupe to close it on.  Much more valid close reason.

Comment: Thanks @DStanley, you're right of course.  Good answer, too bad you're seen as a rep hunter. `;-)`

Comment: @paqogomez, for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350744/c-sharp-accessing-variables-defined-in-different-cs-files

Comment: @CBauer, for a simple reason - it encourages dumb questions like this. And yes, it is dumb for reasons I've already specified.

Comment: @walther, you should probably post on meta about it, it will likely be closed per your dupe suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make this field static in order to access it without creating a class instance. Or create and instance. What suites the best depends on the logic that you want to apply for this class and how it will be used later.

**Instance approach**

```
private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    var settings = new PublicSettings();
    string a = settings.ConnStr;
}
```

**Static field approach**

```
class PublicSettings
    {        
        private static string _ConnStr = "Connection";

        public static string ConnStr
        {
            get
            {
                return _ConnStr;
            }
            set
            {
                _ConnStr = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can't access `this` in a static property

Answer (score 1):

For a connection string, I would either use a Configuration file (app.config) or make the property a static read-only property (since there's often no reason to change a connection string at run-time):

```
class PublicSettings
{        
    public static string ConnStr
    {
        get
        {
            return "Connection";
        }
    }
}
```